# Geometry Node Raycast - ignore occluded faces

Tags: node-editor, geometry

This is based off Chris P's [Frustrum culling](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KoLF99PFLFM), and is part of a larger project. I've broken it down to this example as this is the simplest failure case I can think of.
I've got a set up where I ray cast from a shape to a plane, and instance points based off this, as long as the faces of a cube are pointing towards the plane.

The question I have is how do we use the "nearest" face from Raycasting only, and ignore the occluded internal faces.
The easiest example I can think of is a cube with an extruded internal cavity, see here:
[image: Internal cube faces with instances on them]

The node setup is as follows, and all the culling/front facing faces work well but I still have geometry being created on the inside of the cube.
[image: Geometry node setup for instancing on raycast points]

Any ideas on how to solve this with Geometry Nodes?

Comment: I think rays are cast from all geometry to the plane, so there is no info where rays intersect the geometry they are cast from. There is no way to determine what is 'occluded' in the geometry that rays are cast from and what's not. If the rays were cast from the plane to the geometry, then it might be different.